# Test class code coverage issue

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Below class facing test class code coverage as of now the code coverage is 67%.The problem is OpportunityTeamMember part is not covering.

Test Class:

```
@isTest(seealldata=true)

private class OppDealApexTest{     
    static testMethod void OppDealApex()
    {

      // Id profileId = [select Id from Profile where Name = 'System Administrator'].Id;
        User u =[select id,UserRole.name from user where id =: userinfo.getUserid() limit 1];
        User u1 =[select id from user where id !=: u.id  limit 1];
       // Id devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Renewal').getRecordTypeId();

        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name='TestAcc';
        acc.salesAreaList__c = '';
        acc.BillingCountry = 'SLOVAKIA';
        acc.BillingCity = 'Sample city';
        acc.BillingStreet = 'Sample street';
        acc.ShippingCountry = 'SLOVAKIA';
        acc.SAP_Customer_Number__c = '123';
        acc.CSN__c='CSN1234';
        insert acc;

        Account accNew = new Account();
        accNew.Name='TestAcc2';
        accNew.salesAreaList__c = '';
        accNew.BillingCountry = 'SLOVAKIA';
        accNew.BillingCity = 'test city';
        accNew.BillingStreet = 'test street';
        accNew.ShippingCountry = 'SLOVAKIA';         
        accNew.CSN__c='CSN1234';
        insert accNew;

        Opportunity Opp = new opportunity();
        opp.AccountId = accNew.Id;
        Opp.Name = 'Opportunity record';       
        Opp.CloseDate = system.today()-3;
        Opp.Amount = 100;      
        Opp.StageName = 'Discovery';          
       Opp.won_Loss_Reason__c = 'Test';                 

        insert Opp;     

       test.starttest();
        List<OpportunityTeamMember> optmlist = new List<OpportunityTeamMember>();
        OpportunityTeamMember oppTeam = new OpportunityTeamMember();
        oppTeam.Userid = u.Id;
        oppTeam.OpportunityId = opp.Id;

        optmlist.add(oppTeam);

        OpportunityTeamMember oppTeam1 = new OpportunityTeamMember();
        oppTeam1.Userid = u1.Id;
        oppTeam1.OpportunityId = opp.Id;         
        optmlist.add(oppTeam1);
        insert optmlist;
        system.assertequals(optmlist.size(),2); 

        Opportunity_Splits__c OppOrderSplit = new Opportunity_Splits__c();          
        OppOrderSplit.Name = 'Test';
        OppOrderSplit.Opportunity__c = opp.id;         
        insert OppOrderSplit;          


    }


}
```

Comment: Please do not remove code from your (vandalize) posts. If you do not wish for your code to be public then do not post it on public forums. Removing the code degrades the quality of the question and the context of the answers. Additionally, the code remains visible in the history so removing it does not actually remove the ability to see the code

Answer (score 4):

Change your unit test to SeeAllData=false. Your query is currently querying some random opportunity from your database, not the one you've carefully prepared. You can then also remove the conditional query string from your live code. Also, to get more coverage, you should optimize your map population routines; place the actual logic in a function, then call that function.

```
public static void addMemberToOppMap(Map<Id, List<OpportunityTeamMember>> roleMap, OpportunityTeamMember member) {
  OpportunityTeamMember[] temp = roleMap.get(member.OpportunityId);
  if(temp == null) {
    roleMap.put(member.OpportunityId, temp = new OpportunityTeamMember[0]);
  }
  temp.add(member);
}
```

Then, elsewhere in your code:

```
addMemberToOppMap(OppTeamMapChannelRoles, opptm);
```

which would replace:

```
            if(OppTeamMapChannelRoles.containskey(opptm.OpportunityId))
                OppTeamMapChannelRoles.get(opptm.OpportunityId).add(opptm);
            else{
                List<OpportunityTeamMember> optm = new List<OpportunityTeamMember>();
                optm.add(opptm);
                OppTeamMapChannelRoles.put(opptm.OpportunityId,optm);
            }
        }
```

For your other list, you can inline similar logic; this function doesn't require you to have multiple records for 100% coverage.